# System.AggregateException: One or more errors occured ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.DesignerRemoteException

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have been working in storyboard designing app for IOS. No code, besides automatically generated one is written. After reopening storyboard file in Xamarin I got following error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occured ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.DesignerRemoteException: System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage,System.String].set_Item (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage key, System.String value) in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:216
    at MonoTouch.Design.Server.ImageResourceManager.SetImage (System.String name, MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage value) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1089/7d45bbe2/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Server/ImageResourceManager.cs:79
    at MonoTouch.Design.Server.SessionController+<PostImageResource>c__AnonStorey3.<>m__0 () in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1089/7d45bbe2/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Server/SessionController.cs:167
    at MonoTouch.Design.NativeExtensions+<SafeInvokeOnMainThread>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1089/7d45bbe2/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Server/Util/NativeExtensions.cs:378
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x0007f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1089/7d45bbe2/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:195 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[Object] (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00004] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1089/7d45bbe2/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:202 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.PostResources (MonoTouch.Design.DesignSession session, MonoTouch.Design.ImageResource[] resources) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1089/7d45bbe2/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:132 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession+<SendImageResources>c__AnonStorey13.<>m__1 () [0x00019] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1089/7d45bbe2/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:1329 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker+FuncInvoke`1[System.Object].Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task owner, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task context) [0x00000] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.6.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/TaskActionInvoker.cs:242 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00031] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.6.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/Task.cs:548 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x000d0] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.6.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/Task.cs:438
```

Can anybody help to figure out what this means?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the error is caused by the following:

iOS Designer opens the StoryBoard and tries to parse the XML inside.
Upon parsing it calls MonoTouch.Design.Server (which probably runs code against Xcode for rendering the XML). While doing so it encounters a ViewElement containing a UIImage. So then it tries to setup the UIImage using parameters stored in a Dictionary (filled using the same XML). When it tries to access that Dictionary for the parameters to yield to UIImage it puts in a 'null' for the key and this causes your error.

Now I don't know exactly what in your Storyboard causes this error as you haven't provided the Storyboard-file in question (nor can I guarantee I could find that error if you had), but you can try some of the following things to try and resolve the issue.

- Try and open the Storyboard in Xcode instead of iOS Designer. It sometimes manages to fix corrupt Storyboards that iOS Designer can't handle.
- Open the Storyboard in XML-view and have a look at the elements that have UIImages in them. Try and see if anyone of them has a 'strange' name, source, value or something.
- Post the Storyboard here and see if anyone else can spot the error

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar scenario in that the error message started exactly as in the original post. I could not open the storyboard both in Visual Studio 2015 and in Xamarin Studio 5.10.3 (build 51)

After spending some time in comparing the changes to the .csproj file i figured out that the image for ipad caused this issue for me. I do not know the actual reason for the original post but for me, i had an image to be used as the app logo for ipad and i had named it as "imagename@ipad.png". It turns out this freaks out the designer even though XCode 7 perfectly opens the storyboard.

Finally i renamed the image as "imagename~iPad.png" and that did the trick. Both VS 2015 and XS 5.10.3 are happy to open the storyboard!

Documentation from Xamarin below for working with images

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/sizes-and-filenames/